# when using "git add ." it only add the folder to repository without its content

Tags: git, github

- Problem

when I follow all the steps to upload a project to git :

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

only an empty folder with the name of the project is uploaded
I also tried 
git add --all   instead of  git add .
but it didn't solve the problem
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNMXp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't "save" empty folders. You must have at least one file inside the folder.

Looks like you have `.gitignore` or any other file inside the folder.

go into your folder and do this:

```
# print the list of files in this folder
cd <folder>
Windows: dir
Unix:    ls -la
```

#### How to see what files git will add?

```
# cd <folder>
git status
```

Now you will see the files form this folder and its children which will be added to git when executing `git add .`

Comment: i'm using git bash on windows i found hidden file .gitignore inside the folder but i could not modifie it